# links not working in HTML5

Tags: css, html

I have created a nav bar at the top of my website but for some reason some of the links are not working? I have tried loads of things to change this but can not figure out what is wrong. If anyone has any advice, it would be greatly appropriated.

HTML5 code

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="top-level-menu">
            <a href="index.html">home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="top-level-menu">
            <a href="venue.html">venue</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="venue.html#address">address</a></li>
                    <li><a href="venue.html#background">venue background</a></li>
                    <li><a href="venue.html#instructors">instructors</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="top-level-menu">
            <a href="wakeboarding.html">wakeboarding</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="wakeboarding.html">background</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="wakeboarding.html">future</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="top-level-menu">
            <a href="events.html">events</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="events.html">professional</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="events.html">amateur</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="top-level-menu">
            <a href="prices.html">prices</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="prices.html">prices</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="events.html">special offers</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="top-level-menu">
            <a href="contact.html">contact us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS code

```
ul {
    list-style: none;

}

li {

    display:inline;
    font-size: 26px;
    left: 200px;
    top: 75px;
    padding: 80px;
    font-family: Geneva,Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif; 
    }

body nav .top-level-menu {
    position: relative;
    //cursor: pointer;
}

body nav .top-level-menu:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

body nav .sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: -40px;
    top: 110px;

}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What have you tried?

Comment: That `top value looks a little precise on the submenu. I just generally use `top:100%`. Also the `left` and `top` values on the `li` are probably the culprit.

Comment: It's not that complicated... the links aren't working.

Comment: I'm noticing a few issues right off the bat. For one, you're using `//` to comment out a line of CSS, but that's not how you comment CSS. CSS is commented like this `/* */` Additionally, you have 80px padding on all `li` elements which will cause overlapping padding on your `sub-menu` line items, which could be preventing your links from working.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gbvecnnf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue comes from overlapping padding from other li elements and it covers the links preventing them from being clicked on.

A quick solution is to remove the following line of css to confirm what I am saying is correct.

`li{display:inline;}`

To resolve this issue you may want to reduce the padding for each li element from 80px to something smaller.

`li{padding:0px;}`

Comment: Thanks :) Worked perfectly

Comment: I don't understand why people don't upvote -_- even to the good answers.